# Unable to set focus to a textarea, when the page loads

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, syncfusion

I am trying to set the focus on a syncfusion textarea but I am unable to do so. I have used the this.$nextTick when the component mounts as defined [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/) but the system still does not focus on the textarea.
I have added the same "focus to textarea" code in the `created` event because somehow the `created` event is triggered after the `mounted` event.
I have re-created the issue [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-kjwdx?file=/src/App.vue).
I also see that `this.$refs.vocabularies.$el` returns `input#vocabularies.e-control.e-textbox.e-lib`.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

```
<template>
            <ejs-textbox cssClass="height:500px;" id='vocabularies' :multiline="true" placeholder="Enter your vocabularies" floatLabelType="Auto" :input= "inputHandler" v-model="vocabularies" ref="vocabularies"/>
</template>
<script>
import '@syncfusion/ej2-base/styles/material.css';
import '@syncfusion/ej2-vue-inputs/styles/material.css';    
export default
{
    data() {
        return {
            vocabularies: '',
            inputHandler: (args) => 
            {
                args.event.currentTarget.style.height = "auto";
                args.event.currentTarget.style.height = (args.event.currentTarget.scrollHeight)+"px";
            },
        }
    },
    mounted() 
    {       
        this.$nextTick(function()
        {
            this.$refs.vocabularies.$el.style.height = "auto";
            this.$refs.vocabularies.$el.style.height = (this.$refs.vocabularies.$el.scrollHeight)+"px";
            this.$refs.vocabularies.$el.focus();
        console.log(`mounted run`);
        });
    },
    async created() 
    {
        this.$nextTick(function()
        {
            this.$refs.vocabularies.$el.style.height = "auto";
            this.$refs.vocabularies.$el.style.height = (this.$refs.vocabularies.$el.scrollHeight)+"px";
            this.$refs.vocabularies.$el.focus();
            console.log(`created run`);
        });
    }, 
</script>
```

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html

Comment: Is it possible to create a live demo of this problem ?

Comment: @Himanshu, I have tried using a custom directive in my application and it did not work. I also commented out the created event to see if that helps (but it does not).

Comment: In that case, it'd be better if you can share some fiddle.

Comment: Hello @Himanshu, Here'e a codesandbox link for the issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-kjwdx?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: There's no focus method available on this.$refs.vocabularies.$el. So, doing this.$refs.vocabularies.$el.focus() won't be of any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by using `this.$refs.vocabularies.focusIn();` in the `mounted()` method, based on the documentation [here](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/vue/documentation/api/textbox/#focusin)

Answer (score 0):

So, here's how I've solved it. I am not so sure regarding how good of an approach this is as I haven't worked with syncfusion, so can't say if there might be a better way.

```
<ejs-textbox cssClass="test" id='vocabularies' :multiline="true" placeholder="Enter your vocabularies" floatLabelType="Auto" :input= "inputHandler" v-model="vocabularies" ref="vocabularies"/>
```

Then in mounted I did

```
mounted() {
 let a = document.getElementsByClassName('test')[0];
 a.children[1].focus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can focus the text area by using the **focusIn** public method of the TextBox component in the created event. Kindly refer the below code,

```
    <ejs-textbox cssClass="height:500px;" id='vocabularies' :multiline="true" placeholder="Enter your vocabularies" floatLabelType="Auto" :input= "inputHandler" v-model="vocabularies" ref="vocabularies" :created='onCreated' />


     onCreated:function(){
         this.$refs.vocabularies.ej2Instances.focusIn()
     }
```

Please find the sample from the below link,

Sample Link:

https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/quickstart1111977605